# Cycle through a folder and save all txt files as Excel files (specific formating)

Tags: excel, vba, scripting, filesystemobject

I want to import .txt files from a folder to Excel and save them as Excel files.

The codes are not complete but the cycle through a folder part doesn't work in both of them.

It worked once, but it opened too many folders at once and froze up. I had to quit the program without saving and since then it doesn't work.

Here is the first code:

```
Sub getDataFromWbs()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Set fso = CreateObject(“Scripting.FileSystemObject”)
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("E:\MA\05_Sensordaten\Test\TEST2\")

For Each wbFile In fldr.Files
    If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = “.txt” Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)
        wb.Close
    End If
Next wbFile

End Sub
```

I get the following error with `Set fso = CreateObject(“Scripting.FileSystemObject”)`

> runtime error 424
>   object necessary

I also tried the `dir` approach:

```
Sub LoopImport2()

'Loop through all files in a folder

Dim FN As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FN = Dir("E:\MA\05_Sensordaten\Test\TEST2\*.txt")

While FN <> ""

    'Insert the actions to be performed on each file

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename = FN, Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
      xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
      Array(2, 1)), DecimalSeparator:=",", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        ActiveSheet.Name = FN
        ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "0.00"

    'Set the FN to the next file
    FN = Dir

Wend

End Sub
```

and get this error:

> runtime error 1004 application or object defined error

With this part:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename = FN, Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
  xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
  Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
  Array(2, 1)), DecimalSeparator:=",", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first code, please, try:

`Dim fso As Object` and `“Scripting.FileSystemObject”` looks having strange double quote characters. Try using `"Scripting.FileSystemObject"`.

In second one, please change `Filename = FN` with `FileName:= FN`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!
the first one works now, so i will use that.

Comment: @Daniel Gößeringer: If it solved your problem, ticking the left code side check box will make it accepted answer. In this way, somebody looking for something similar, will know that it worked...